# If $G$ is a finite $p$-group with $Z(G) = [G,G]$, then $\exp(G/Z(G)) = \exp(Z(G))$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

*What I have done so far*:

Let $(G,*)$ be a finite non-trivial group 
with $Z(G) = [G,G]$, that is, $G/Z(G)$ is Abelian.

Define $n := \exp(G/Z(G))$ and $s := n-1$ and $m := \exp(Z(G))$.

Since $\exp(G/Z(G)) = n$, it follows $\forall x \in G: x^n \in Z(G)$ and $\forall x \in G\ \exists z \in Z(G): x^n = z \wedge x = x^{-(n-1)}*z = x^{-s}*z$.

From $Z(G) = [G,G]$ it follows that every commutator of $G$ commutes with every other element in $G$.

Let $x,y \in G$.

$[x,y] = 
x*y*x^{-1}*y^{-1} = 
(x^{-s}*z)*y*(x^{-s}*z)^{-1}*y^{-1} = 
x^{-s}*z*y*z^{-1}*x^{s}*y^{-1} = 
x^{-s}*y*x^{s}*y^{-1} = 
[x^{-s},y] = [x,y]^{-s}$

So $[x,y]^n = [x,y]^{1+s} = 1$.

We know $\forall w \in G'\ \exists r \in \mathbb N_+\ \exists a_1,...,a_r,b_1,...,b_r \in G\ \exists \ell_1,...,\ell_r \in \mathbb Z: 
w = [a_1,b_1]^{\ell_1}*...*[a_r,b_r]^{\ell_r}$.

With $Z(G) = [G,G]$ we infer $w^n = 
([a_1,b_1]^{\ell_1}*...*[a_r,b_r]^{\ell_r})^n = 
([a_1,b_1]^{\ell_1})^n*...*([a_r,b_r]^{\ell_r})^n = 
([a_1,b_1]^n)^{\ell_1}*...*([a_r,b_r]^n)^{\ell_r} = 
1^{\ell_1}*...*1^{\ell_r} = 1$

So $\forall w \in G': ord(w) \leq n$ and $\exp(Z(G)) = m \leq n = \exp(G/Z(G))$.

We assume $n > 1$ and $G$ is a $p$-group, that is, $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb N_+: n = p^{n_0}$.

Let $x \in G\setminus Z(G)$ such that $ord(x Z(G)) = p^{n_0} = \exp(G/Z(G))$.

By choice of $x$ and definition of $n$ it follows $\forall \ell \in \mathbb N_+: (\ell < n_0) \supset (x^{p^\ell} \notin Z(G))$,
that is, $\exists y \in G: [y,x^{p^{n_0-1}}] \not= 1$.

Note $\forall \ell \in \mathbb N_+: [y,x^{p^{\ell}}] = [y,x]^{p^{\ell}}$ because every commutator in $G$ commutes with every element of $G$.

Moreover, $[y,x]^{p^{n_0}} = [y,x^{p^{n_0}}] = 1$ because $x^{p^{n_0}} \in Z(G)$.
Thus, $ord([y,x]) \leq p^{n_0}$.

If $ord([y,x]) = p^{n_0} = n$, then $n = ord([y,x]) \leq \exp(G') = \exp(Z(G)) = m \leq n$.

**Question**: Why is $ord([y,x]) < p^{n_0}$ impossible? This last step eludes me.
Thank you for your thoughts!!

Comment: Some thoughts on writing style: avoid using quantifiers this much. If possible, don't use quantifiers at all, unless you are working on set theory or logic. Also, there's no need to specify the group operation by writing `*`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will try and apply it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption $[y,x]^{p^{n_0-1}} = [y,x^{p^{n_0-1}}] \ne 1$. Since $o([y,x])$ is a power of $p$. it must be greater than $p^{n_0-1}$, so it must be $p^{n_0}$.